# Android - draw text on pdf using itext

Tags: android, pdf

In my application, I am showing one pdf of examination form and user can answer on that pdf.

It's same like online form filling. User can answer on pdf in front of respective question.

How can i draw answer text on that pdf while user answered ?

Can anyone help me please ? How can i do that ? Any link ?

Thanks.

Comment: [http://api.itextpdf.com/?__hstc=139321324.6c7033925388fab6e06a5c239ff90b3e.1349681572522.1349681572522.1349681572522.1&__hssc=139321324.1.1349681572522]         [http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php]